#  issue on posting with rich text editor in aspnet mvc and jquery 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, rich-text-editor

So, I'm trying to implement this rich text editor by jquery (jqueryrte.com) and it's giving me the following errors when I'm posting some edited values for a text area.

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (Model.Description="...wn and track athletes ...").

I saw something to fix this where you turn off validation for it. I also read about some kind of white listing tags and stuff. But it's my first time to use this kind of plug in and I'm a little worried about being vulnerable about JavaScript attacks. Looking for advice on how I should deal with this issue.

Comment: Can you show your controller definition and maybe some relevant portion of your view?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information from your question I can tell you:

You should add the following attribute to the action method that gets the request from your rich text box.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Add(string richtext)
{
}
```

This will not check for dangerous code just for the parameters on that Action method.

To whitelist for dangerous tags you may want to look at Microsoft AntiXss library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx

Comment: Yeah I know about that part. I was trying to avoid that as I didn't want to complicate things with whitelisting tags. Unless that's the only option ..